# Выбор структуры mysql таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица, 100,000 строк

```
table_1
- id
- param_50_10
- param_500_5
- tinyint
- year
```

Поле param_50_10 демонстрирует необходимость хранить до 10 значений (3 цифры типа 123,456) из 50 возможных комбинаций

Поле param_500_5 - хранить до 5 значений (тоже 3 цифры) из возможных 500

tinyint хранит 1 число из возможных 200

year хранит год

Пользователь запрашивает информацию с любыми из этих обьектов в любой комбинации, например он запрашивает все строки, в которых в param_50_10 есть a or b or c строка, либо же and вместо or, то же самое с полем 500_5, и дополнительно фильтрует по year и tinyint

Если создадим таблицу под param_50_10 со списками параметр - цель, то будет таблица 500к строк

Под 500_5 - 250к

Как фильтровать, по этой схеме через join ?  Или сделать одну таблицу с 15 колонками и поиск значений в каждой?

Comment: Читайте про фасетный поиск. В т.ч. про рекомендуемые структуры для хранения исходных данных.

Comment: На английском через автопернвод тяжело